# Opening a terminal from Python regardless of the Distro

Tags: shell, gnome, python, gnome-terminal

I'm developing a multiplatform `Django` project that opens a new terminal and automatically enters a Docker container, leveraging `docker exec`. Since this application must be OS agnostic, it is able to do it on Windows, MacOS and Linux.

This is how I implemented it:

```
current_os = platform.system()
exec_command = f"docker exec -it {container_id} /bin/{shell}"
if current_os == "Windows":
    command = f"start powershell /c {exec_command}"
elif current_os == "Darwin":
    command = f"osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"{exec_command}\"'"
elif current_os == "Linux":
    command = f"gnome-terminal -- sh -c \"{exec_command}\""  # TODO tests
else:
    raise Exception("An unknown OS was detected. Unable to open a terminal.")

if os.system(command) != 0:
    raise Exception("There was an error opening a new terminal.")
```

My doubt is: does `gnome-terminal` actually work on most distros? If not, how could I handle it? How faultproof is it? Browsing the internet didn't lead me to actual solutions. 
Keep in mind that I'd like to run commands automatically when opening the terminal, and I need a property that prevents the terminal from closing after running the command.

I could only test the Linux case on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It's not so much distro-specific as installation specific. I don't have `gnome-terminal` installed (on Debian) for instance. Another problem with your linux command is that you use `bash` in the terminal, `bash` is another thing that might not be available everywhere.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity as I thought. I could use `sh` which is truly OS agnostic, but still, thank you for the observation!

Comment: interesting question! something similar to `xdg` is the idea... the only thing I've found is this [https://gitlab.com/thayne/xdgterm]; maybe you can some kind of epiphany...

Comment: @mattia.b89 will check it very willingly! Thank you all for the attention

Comment: Why open a new terminal? Wouldn't a call to os.exec... or subprocess.run be enough?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani the goal is to open an interactive tty terminal, to enter a container and operate it. Still, the main problem is what command to run to make it completely multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

As folks have already pointed out, there is no such thing as "Linux". There is "Debian", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo", etc, and variants of these. While you can be sure that all of those will have `/bin/sh` available, you *cannot* assume that any particular terminal application will be installed.

You could create a list of common terminal applications and then iterate through them until you find one that works, something like:

```
import random
import subprocess

class NoTerminalError(Exception):
    pass

possible_terminals = [
        ('lxterminal', lambda cmd: ['lxterminal', '-e', '/bin/sh', '-c', cmd]),
        ('xfce4-terminal', lambda cmd: ['xfce4-terminal', '-x', '/bin/sh', '-c', cmd]),
        ('xterm', lambda cmd: ['xterm', '-e', '/bin/sh', '-c', cmd]),
        ('gnome-terminal', lambda cmd: ['gnome-terminal', '--', "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd]),
        ]

def find_terminal():
    random.shuffle(possible_terminals)
    for name, cmdline in possible_terminals:
        try:
            subprocess.run(cmdline("/bin/true"), check=True)
            return name, cmdline
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass

    raise NoTerminalError()


name, cmdline = find_terminal()
print('using terminal', name)
subprocess.run(cmdline('cmatrix'), check=True)
```

Or you could just include in your documentation, "this program requires *insert_name_here*".

Comment: The answer is correct, unfortunately there's no standard way of launching up _some_ terminal emulator. That being said, I highly recommend to have a way for the _user_ to specify which one he prefers, rather than you (the developer) coming up with a hardwired priority list. You could, for example, try to start `x-terminal-emulator` first, which is Debian's/Ubuntu's way of starting the user's favorite, and even in other distros the user can create such a wrapper or symlink for himself to specify his favorite.

Comment: This is a good idea! I know there is no such thing as "Linux", but that is the value returned by `platform.system()`